# Pandas series as namedtuple

Tags: python, pandas

I am accessing pandas data frame rows and as a result I get pandas series.
My parsing routines accept namedtuples. 
Is it possible to convert pandas series to named tuple?

Comment: Note, `df.itertuples()` returns an iterator which, by default, returns `namedtuple` objects for rows...

Comment: Please provide some sample input and (expected) sample output.

Comment: hit = master.data_frame.loc[invoice.Id] - series
now I would like to convert hit to namedtuple

Comment: @Mateusz in the future, please provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 8):

General purpose function to convert any series into a namedtuple

```
def namedtuple_me(s, name='S'):
    return namedtuple(name, s.index)(*s)

namedtuple_me(pd.Series([1, 2, 3], list('abc')))
S(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

---

For improved implementation courtesy of @juanpa.arrivillaga

```
import functools
from collections import namedtuple

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)  # add memoization to increase speed
def _get_class(fieldnames, name):
    """Create a new namedtuple class."""
    return namedtuple(name, fieldnames)

def namedtuple_me(series, name='S'):
    """Convert the series to a namedtuple."""
    klass = _get_class(tuple(series.index), name)
    return klass._make(series)
```

Comment: yes, I should have probably used `.index` but I assumed a `pd.DataFrame` starting point. One minor thing, although this may just bother me because I am insane, but instead of re-creating a new class, possibly with the same exact fields, i'd cache the classes! Super easy if you modify `namedtuple_me` to return use a helper that returns a `namedtuple` class, and simply decorate it with `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)`

Comment: Super good idea.  And oh yeah, your post is far superior if going to utilize over multiple rows in a dataframe.  Also, you're exposing my ignorance.  I have to go look up `functools.lru_cache`

Comment: feel free to add to your answer: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/a6efe3de57548b17429fffb8a5d08b2e

Answer (score 5):

You can probably just use `df.itertuples` for whatever you are doing:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
     c0    c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7    c8    c9
0   8.0   2.0   1.0   4.0   4.0   3.0   1.0  19.0   5.0   9.0
1   7.0   7.0   0.0   4.0  14.0   7.0   9.0   0.0   0.0   9.0
2  19.0  10.0   6.0  13.0  12.0  11.0   8.0   4.0  11.0  13.0
3  14.0   0.0  16.0  19.0   3.0   8.0   8.0   9.0  17.0  13.0
4  18.0  16.0  10.0   8.0  15.0   9.0  18.0   9.0   5.0  10.0
5  15.0   7.0  16.0   3.0  18.0  14.0   3.0   6.0   0.0   9.0
6  14.0  14.0  18.0   4.0   4.0   0.0   8.0  15.0   8.0  12.0
7  19.0  16.0  15.0  16.0   1.0  12.0  14.0   1.0  10.0  15.0
8   8.0  17.0  10.0  18.0   7.0  13.0  13.0  12.0   6.0  11.0
9  15.0  13.0  13.0  17.0   2.0   0.0   6.0  10.0   5.0   5.0

In [6]: rows = df.itertuples(name='Row')

In [7]: r0 = next(rows)

In [8]: r0
Out[8]: Row(Index=0, c0=8.0, c1=2.0, c2=1.0, c3=4.0, c4=4.0, c5=3.0, c6=1.0, c7=19.0, c8=5.0, c9=9.0)

In [9]: r0.c0
Out[9]: 8.0
```

Otherwise, you'll have to do it yourself, something like:

```
In [10]: from collections import namedtuple

In [11]: df.columns
Out[11]: Index(['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9'], dtype='object')

In [12]: Row = namedtuple('Row', df.columns)

In [13]: df.iloc[0]
Out[13]:
c0     8.0
c1     2.0
c2     1.0
c3     4.0
c4     4.0
c5     3.0
c6     1.0
c7    19.0
c8     5.0
c9     9.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64

In [14]: Row(*df.iloc[0])
Out[14]: Row(c0=8.0, c1=2.0, c2=1.0, c3=4.0, c4=4.0, c5=3.0, c6=1.0, c7=19.0, c8=5.0, c9=9.0)
```

Note, this version doesn't have an `index` field...

Comment: I would like to but the problem is that i get series (one row): master.data_frame.loc[invoice.Id] - series.
And I woule like to convert it to named tuple.

Comment: @Mateusz sure, added an exaple of a quick-and-dirty approach

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about it, if what you have in hand is already a Pandas Series and if you're using it as input to a function, is to unpack the Series as-is.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Sally'], 'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01'], 'value': ['A', 'B']})
>>> df
    name        date value
0   John  2020-01-01     A
1  Sally  2020-02-01     B
>>> row = df.iloc[0]
>>> type(row)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> print({**row})  # unpacks as a dictionary
{'name': 'John', 'date': '2020-01-01', 'value': 'A'}
>>> myfunc(**row)   # ergo, unpacks as keyword args
```

This is because a Pandas `Series` is already a `namedtuple`-like object (and it's exactly what `df.itertuples` returns).

Anyway, for the problem I was trying to solve I was taking a specific row of the dataframe rather than iterating over the whole thing, and so I didn't need to go the route of converting to a named tuple.